# google maps show polygons from shapefile

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a question about opportunities With Google maps.

We have a shapfile with a set of polygons, all polygons have a unique id. Will it be possible to highligh some of the polygons from a list/db or something with the id of the polygons to highlight?
And will it be possible to add id or remove id from that list when click polygons in the map?

If anyone have some links i can look at it will be great, to find out where to start..

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my poor English:)

Comment: The answer is yes.  What you request can all be done.  But this is too much for 1 question.  I would advise to ask 1 question about that shapefile, and keep the database stuff apart, in another question.  In both cases: give more details.  I would like to see this shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your're answer. I think i found out how to display the shape file. I need to convert it to kml file.

This is now how the kml file looks like:

```
<Placemark id="0">
  <Snippet maxLines="0">RÃ…STAD - SOLLÃ˜KKA</Snippet>
  <name>0706706</name>
  <description>&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;table border="1"padding="1"width="97%"&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;ID:&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;0706706&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;</description>
  <visibility>1</visibility>
  <open>0</open>
  <Polygon>
    <extrude>1</extrude>
    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
    <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
    <outerBoundaryIs>
      <LinearRing>
        <coordinates>10.2523636384489,59.1447359102789,0 10.2491296302902,59.1395560791909,0 10.2532230162908,59.1374941167945,0 10.263360691017,59.1367043657945,0 10.2634595062511,59.1384376257802,0 10.2649309077057,59.1394572514333,0 10.269233770364,59.1400441116529,0 10.2697022332493,59.1403216454834,0 10.270226363019,59.1403798402083,0 10.2712874576306,59.1407701469098,0 10.2797498489266,59.1407388533888,0 10.284476754492,59.1393075261033,0 10.3213655748521,59.1198007555867,0 10.3244406119112,59.1201186543517,0 10.330913554855,59.1294550046376,0 10.3317127328163,59.139828002045,0 10.3248919998049,59.1539487711044,0 10.3215362102992,59.1626071415408,0 10.3197868790073,59.1680633313157,0 10.3092533751796,59.1704360002405,0 10.3010112944765,59.1753917058148,0 10.2839272303475,59.1785670163406,0 10.2809551476738,59.1814412337641,0 10.2771550018462,59.1831332052011,0 10.2754038754411,59.1837791037246,0 10.2626393488688,59.1879021502356,0 10.2598018937944,59.1724670783896,0 10.2570474792395,59.1625631845719,0 10.2636028932216,59.1621701468898,0 10.2659526888692,59.1648279737181,0 10.2680633144255,59.1643948170748,0 10.2779341266802,59.1564481861203,0 10.2756177183904,59.1513466643591,0 10.2523636384489,59.1447359102789,0 </coordinates>
      </LinearRing>
    </outerBoundaryIs>
  </Polygon>
  <styleUrl>#trb2</styleUrl>
</Placemark>
```

The name are the id of the polygon. Now i try to give all polygons a color..

Any help?